# Максимальное количество файлов в папке Linux и Windows

Tags: linux, windows, сервер

Вопрос не из простых

Сколько можно сохранить картинок в папке в Linux

т.е. допустим у меня 9 000 000 000 000 000 000 картинок

я создаю древовидную иерархию из папок

у меня допустим 5 ветвей, ограничение на число файлов и папок в ветви 6179

тогда общее количество возможно загружаемых файлов равно 6179 в 5 степени и равно

9 007 224 264 576 426 899 т.е. BIGINT (почти из за округления)

**Теперь сам вопрос**

Как определить максимальное возможное число файлов в папке или папок в папке в Linux и тоже самое в windows для сравнения?

Моя иерархия будет нормально работать?

Что думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: К чему вопрос вообще? причем тут SSH и SERVER?

Почему сравниваются window и linux?

Что было прочитано по поводу файловых систем?

Comment: - Мне почему-то кажется, что, если у вас 9 000 000 000 000 000 000 картинок и на сервере хватает места, чтобы хранить их, то нужно запихнуть их все в 1 pack-файл, построить индекс и добавлять новые элементы с конца.

- Если вам при этом нужна возможность удаления существующих элементов, то осуществляйте отложенное удаление. Например, раз в месяц вы находите все картинки, которые точно можно удалить и атомарно перезаписываете весь pack-файл и индекс, удалив их.

- И да, используйте любое готовое решение для этого, например, [GridFS.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/)

Comment: поменяй метод хранения, так, чтобы в папке хранилось не более N папок + файлов

Comment: м, я отстал от жизни и диски на эскабайты уже есть?

Comment: Теоретически ему нужно просто перейти на LVM, размещенную на нормальной СХД, но на практике, видимо ТС не может себе это позволить.

Answer (score 15):

В FAT32 максимальное количество файлов *на логическом диске* 4,194,304.

В NTFS максимальное количество файлов на логическом диске 4,294,967,295.

В ext4 максимальное количество файлов на логическом диске до 4,294,967,295 (указывается при создании ФС).

Answer (score 11):

8 миллионов терабайт (это 8 эксабайт), если только один файл - один байт...

Согласно [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82), общий объём цифровой информации, имеющейся на земном шаре в 2006 году, составил 161 эксабайт),

Но вот только большинство файловых систем выделяет как минимум 4 килобайта на файл, а это 32 тысячи эксабайт - **немножко** больше, чем существует во всем интернете :). Поэтому - "нет, не будет такая система работать".

С другой стороны, в линуксе (да и в видне) все сильно зависит от файловой системы, но по своему опыту могу сказать, что после 10000 файлов к каталоге независимо от файловой системы, начинаются тормоза.

Но в линуксе есть ещё такое понятие как [inode](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (формально - номерки к файлам). Если они закончатся, то больше файлов не запишете, даже если ещё есть свободное место.

Вывод. Спуститесь с небес. Не будет у Вас сколько картинок. А если и будет - на одном компе их не сохранить (ну по крайней мере в следующие лет 5). Вон даже у инстаграмма [статистика](http://instagrama.ru/) говорит о

> В июле 2011 года было достигнуто число в 100 миллионов загруженных в сервис Instagram фотографий, а к августу таких фотографий стало уже 150 миллионов.

Comment: а как тогда вконтакте работает с фотками?

как сохраняет?

вот если думать по вашей логике, на жестком диске может быть определенное количество файлов

теперь даже если вконтакте все распхает по жестким дискам, то часть дисков будет не использоваться, ведь так?

где логика?

почему жесткий диск нельзя забить до полна и переходить к следующему

Comment: @maxiimkoo учите матчасть

Comment: я правильно понял что на сервере можносоздать только 3203072 файлов?

    -bash-3.2# df -i
    Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
    /dev/hdb             3203072 1516705 1686367   48% /
    /dev/hda1              50800      19   50781    1% /boot
    -bash-3.2#

Comment: можно разбить на несколько партиций.

>  может быть определенное количество файлов

да, и больше нет.

> почему жесткий диск нельзя забить до полна и переходить к следующему

да можно. просто не влезет такое кол-во файлов на один диск.

Comment: Ладно, задам вопрос по другому

у меня 7 000 000 текстовых файлов по несколько килобайт

как их запихнуть на мой сервер?

в моем случае файлы влезут и жесткий диск еще будет свободным, но вся проблема в ограничении

Comment: контакт кидает каждую новую фотку на определенный сервер, который выбирается случайно из  списка новых "незабитых" серверов, тем самым загрузка идет быстрее и забивается пространство на разных серверах. + ко всему у них есть разграничение какие потоки и какой информации куда летят, видео допустим у них все хранится в Москве, аудио отчасти тоже, фотки в Питере.

Comment: @maxiimkoo, IMHO у Вас файловая ext4. Вообще, ее тип можете посмотреть

     df -Ti 


Число  инодов (для ext4) вычисляется при ее создании и его можно задать флагом -i (см. man mkfs.ext4), хоть по одному иноду на дисковый блок. Только вот место под них в этот момент зарезервируется и для данных будет уже недоступно.

Про ext3 не помню, но возможно  в именно ней не было ограничения на количество инодов (в какой-то из линуксовых ФС его точно не было), т.е. иноды динамически выделялись, пока есть место на диске.

Comment: 7 миллионов файлов? я бы сделал 256 каталогов (00 .. ff), в которые ещё по 256 каталогов. Итого в каждом будет по 100 файлов. в какую папку файл забросить - рассчитывается md5 хеш от имени и первые 4 символа и определят. У меня подобная система несколько лет проработала и никаких замечаний (специально посмотрел на один с серверов - около 5 миллионов файлов. средний размер 4-10 кб, 35 Гб всего).

Конечно, нужно смотреть на имена файлов, может быть можно будет просто последовательно забивать.

Comment: @KoVadim, сейчас-то у него на эту ФС эти 7 млн. не влезут. Надо делать новую ФС с большим к-вом инодов.

В принципе текущую можно скомпактировать и урезать. Потом разбить диск и в новом разделе сделать ФС с нужным к-вом инодов.

Comment: @KoVadim, @avp а почему мне эта высокоинтеллектуальная дискуссия напоминает анекдот на тему: "И как же это ёжики трахаются? Тут иголки, и тут иголки...". Если 7млн. картинок, то почему домашняя персоналка с NTFS или ext4? И где ТС взял эти 7млн. картинок?

Comment: @avp - а я и не рекомендовал это дело на домашнем компе. Я явно упомянул, что это у меня на сервере.

@alexlz вот где взять 7 миллионов картинок - я представляю. А вот где 9 000 000 000 000 000 000 - нет.

> то почему домашняя персоналка с NTFS 

я тоже не знаю.

Comment: @alexlz, ну, может это кадры какие-то он генерит. Не знаю. 

--

Ничего странного не вижу, если на терабайтный диск человек хочет положить 10 млн маленьких файлов. 

В принципе, по блоку (4K) на файл они займут всего 40 гигов (меньше 5% raw диска).

--

@KoVadim, и я не вижу проблем сделать это (10 млн файлов) на домашнем компе (в той же ext4).

Comment: @kovadim, мне кажется или в логике по расчету md5 по имени мы получим одинаковые хэши для разных файлов с одинаковыми именами? Т.е. вся логика построена на аксиоме - разные файлы не должны иметь одинаковых имён... А как же любимые 111.ext, 123.ext, новый файл.ext...

Comment: А какая файловая система позволят хранить два файла с одинаковым именем в **одном и том же** каталоге? Берите имя с полным (или относительным) путем - будет уникальное имя.

Другое дело, что md5 хеш может оказаться одинаковым для двух различных имен. (такое известно как "коллизия хэшфункции").

Конкретно в моей задаче, которую я таким образом решал, была гарантия, что если два файла имеют одинаковое имя (даже в разных каталогах), то содержимое у них будет идентично.

Comment: @KoVadim - добавляешь текущий timestamp (можно в 64х-ричной системе) и почти полностью исключаешь попадание (если попал, то это уж очень не повезло). для кучи файлов мне больше xfs нравится.