# Хранение большого количества изображений в одной директории на сайте

Tags: linux, администрирование, оптимизация-сайтов

Сайт - доска объявлений, все изображения хранятся в одной папке, количество порядка 40 тысяч. Выводятся изображения напрямую, просто через урл (src="/imgs/1253573.jpg") 
Если ли смысл раскидать на поддиректории (по подразделам сайта например), большой ли будет выигрыш в ресурсах или скорости загрузки? Есть ли какие рекомендации на количество файлов в директории, после которых уменьшается скорость или увеличивается нагрузка?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Я думаю, если не делать листинг (ведь ваш механизм, отдающий картинки, так не делает?), то особых проблем не должно быть.

Comment: Почему бы не протестировать? Так вы точно узнаете )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Введение

Разбивать однозначно стоит, если кол-во файлов превысит 5-7 тысяч. При 10к файлов в одной папке файловой системе уже обычно "стает плохо" - открытие файла отрабатывает дольше, растет нагрузка на диск. При 10к файлов в папке просто удалить все файлы уже [было накладно](https://habrahabr.ru/post/157613/) (то есть, просто `rm *` уже просто так не работает - баш пытается развернуть * в список имен, этот список собрается долго, но потом он оказывается слишком длинным и баш не может выполнить команду. Правда где то в 2011-2012 это чуточку пофикисили, но все равно тяжело). У меня был опыт с подобным и несколько попыток переписать "правильно".

## Теория

Стоит понимать, что разные файловые системы по разному реагируют. Например, ntfs при открытии папки пытаются обновить время последнего доступа. Если файлов много, то это на долго.

Сколько же теоретически можно вместить?

- ntfs. Теоретический предел [2 в 32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS). Реальный - порядка [100k](https://hardforum.com/threads/maximum-number-of-files-in-a-directory.861148/). Но пишут, что все тупит сильно. Также в [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) написано, что GetTempFileName не будет работать, если в каталоге с временными файлами больше 65535 файлов.
- ext3.  [тут все сложно](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#cite_note-1), максимальное кол-во файлов нужно смотреть.
- ext4 - также, как и у ntfs,  [4миллиарда](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4).

Можно ещё почитать другой вопрос на SO - [Максимальное количество файлов в папке Linux и Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/254497/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-linux-%D0%B8-windows)

## Способ первый

Способ складывания по датам плох - он не равномерный. То есть, будут папки, где лежит много файлов и папок, где файлов почти нет. Так как папки в большинстве файловых систем не бесплатны. Второй недостаток - сложность шардирования. То есть, если размер файлов начинает превышать размер файловой системы, то начинаются проблемы. Ещё один недостаток - дубликаты. Их очень сложно отслеживать. Но у этого способа есть только один хороший плюс - легко найти старые файлы.

## Способ второй

Но есть лучше способ, проверенный и используемый многими. Перед помещением файла в "хранилище", для файла считается md5/sha1. Теперь, на основании этого хеша формируется "путь для хранения". Я применял такой - первые два символа определяют папку, в котрой создается папка, имя которой совпадает с следующими двумя символами. А сам файл храниться внутри папки. Пример. Допустим есть файл "test.jpg" и md5 сумма от его содержимого такая "b3e6b7290309113a2d2b392bf1e2084e". Само хранилище находиться в `/srv/archiv`. Значит этот файл будет храниться по такому пути

```
/srv/archiv/b3/e6/b7290309113a2d2b392bf1e2084e_test.jpg
```

Я все таки оставил оригинальное имя файла. Иногда оно нужно. Но можно сохранять имена файлов в базу, тогда можно будет и не писать его.

Плюсы этого способа.

- равномерное распределение файлов по каталогам (обеспечивается хэш функцией).
- легко разнести файлы по серверам. К примеру, первые два символа могут определять имя сервера в кластере (а сами кластера подмонтированы внутрь).
- легко выявляются дубликаты - у них будет одинаковый хэш.
- если допустить, что файловая система легко держит 1000 файлов в папке, то вся система сможет удерживать около 65миллионов файлов (256*256*1000). Если брать минимальные файлы (по 4к), то это  как минимум 250 гигабайт (плюс накладные расходы файловой системы, обычно это 10-20 процентов от размера).
- использование в паре с этим способом ещё и базы данных сильно расширяет возможности.

Минусы:

- хэширование не бесплатно.
- теоретически может оказаться, что у двух разных файлов может оказаться одинаковый хэш.
- сложно удалить "старые файлы", но find может помочь.

## Готовые решения

Есть пример реализации на php - [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/227855/).

На посмотреть:

- [Хранение и доставка контента, Олег Илларионов (ВКонтакте)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5cJDdqKt74)
- [Организация хранения данных, Кортунов](https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/524/)

Comment: Способ, конечно, хороший (да-да, гит), но для свалки файлов, откуда их не собираются удалять сложноват. Плюс, по файлу хеш посчитать для сохранения - это да, а вот по числовому id из базы получить - уже нет, надо базу дорабатывать.

Answer (score 2):

Доброго! Я считаю, что разбить по директориям следует, но не по разделам сайта, а по датам. И обязательно в американском формате: 2016-11-21 (или помесячно, как предлагает Сергей). Применить nginx для обработки статики обязательно (этих самых картинок) - тогда они будут отдаваться пользователю гораздо быстрее

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от файловой системы и ее настроек. Например в ext4 могут закончится inodes см https://toster.ru/q/122827 или https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/4496222

Answer (score 0):

Более целесообразно сделать в таком виде: `/2014/02/*.*`.
Так более структурированно.

А на самом деле, по-моему, без разницы.
Есть практика, когда в директории более 400 000 файлов лежит, и ничего. Конечно, если зайдешь через FTP и сделаешь просмотр файлов, ответ будет долгим...

Answer (score 0):

Если именем файла являются последовательные числа, предлагаю просто разбить по 1000 файлов в папке. Ну или подобрать желаемое значение на основе замеров производительности.

Для того, что складывается как архив и никогда не удаляется, такой способ подойдёт идеально: равное число файлов в папках; просто понять, куда класть, просто достать на основе id из базы.

Если файлы всё же удаляются, можно попробовать поменять местами результат и остаток от деления, например, файл `12345` разместить как `345/12` вместо `12/345`. По теории вероятностей папки получатся примерно одинаковыми независимо от удалений (ну нельзя же сказать, что файлы с чётными id удаляют чаще, чем с нечётными?).

Answer (score 0):

Одно из радикальных решений, что бы не городить костыли с распределением файлов между поддиректориями, это создание отдельного web - сервиса, с админской панелью и реализацией CRUD-операций. Сам этот веб-сервис, будет использовать хранение картинок, как BLOB-объектов, в специальном контейнере в облаке, например в облаке Azure. Или поступить еще проще. А именно, сначала, скачать и установить Azure Storage Explorer для администрирования картинок,
а далее, через него, управлять картинкамм и извлекать ссылки для них.

Вот в этом [коммите](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Mango/commit/1caa210ebcfcf22e7c47dff9147a0b6d9ce8c3cd) репозитория, где используются микро-сервисы для реализации функционала интернет-магазина на .NET 6, используется второй, простейший вариант.